# How to send passwords from a client to a server

Tags: registration, user-registration

I am creating a web service using Jersey.

The service should handle user registration. My plan is to get a registration request which will contain a user name and password, store both of them in a MySql db and fetch it every time the user wants to log in.

I've read that you should encode your password using Base64 before sending it, but it still sound unsecured since if someone intercept it, he can easily decrypt it. So how exactly should the client pass me the user name and password? How should I store them in the db?

Comment: Base64 has zero security. There's no reason to encode a password that way to send it over the wire.

Answer (score 3):

You should not store the password at all. You should store a salted and encrypted blob, which can be reproduced using the password and salt.

Take a look at [`bcrypt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or `scrypt`.

To verify the user has typed the correct password, you extract parameters stored in the password blob and then apply the password to the encryption function (`bcrypt`) with the stored parameters. If the output matches the stored hash, you may consider the user successfully logged in.

The working theory behind this is that you assume someone may have obtained the raw database and also knows exactly how the passwords are stored. If you were to store the passwords directly or trivially encoded, they could simply read these from the data dump (decoding if necessary).

Merely hashing the passwords with a secure hashing function like SHA-3 is also not sufficient for three reasons:

- Without salting your passwords, an attacker could simply create a precomputed list of X most passwords and probably use these to trivially decode a substantial chunk of the passwords in your db by matching them against the lookup table. This works because these hashing functions should always produce the same output for the same input, and because such master lists of "X most common passwords" are readily available on the internet.
- Without salting, once a password is cracked, the attacker could use the input to trivially match other passwords in the same db. This works for the same reason as above.
- These days hashing is pretty fast. So even when you salt your passwords it may not be enough to thwart an attacker armed with lists of most commonly used passwords (they could conceivably brute force salted versions of the most commonly used passwords and build giant lookup tables -- such computing resources are pretty cheap).

Comment: OK that sound like a part of what I need. How can the user send the password itself in a safe way?

Comment: You use an encrypted channel (HTTPS), preferably secured with a cipher suite that provides Forward Secrecy (this way attacks based on traffic analysis to deduce the password from the encrypted traffic will be obstructed).

Comment: Salting in the traditional sense is a complete waste of time. Modern password hashing methods like bcrypt and scrypt will do this for you, and they'll do it properly. They also have a difficulty setting that can be adjusted depending on how secure you need your passwords to be.

Comment: @tadman yes I know this. Which is why I steer away from hashing and towards proper crypt functions in my answer. :)

Comment: It's not so much steering away as refusing to use. The world's a hostile place. bcrypt is an absolute minimum now. My only concern here is you say "you should store a salted, encrypted blob" which isn't really what bcrypt or scrypt produce. They give you a short, neatly-formatted string representation of a cryptographic grade hash. Encryption is a different mechanism than hashing.

Comment: So from what I understand, if the password is sent via an encrypted channel like HTTPS, it can be sent as a plain text, then the server encrypts it using bcrypt and store the result of that encryption (or hash as tadman mentioned). Then when a user wants to login, the same thing happens again and now I fetch the already existing password and just compare what I got stored with the user's input?

Answer (score 0):

Where security is concerned, there is very little difference between your web service and a standard website with a login screen/secure area so all best practices still apply.  The most important of which:

The username and password **must** be sent to the server over a secure, encrypted channel (https for example).  Don't even think about trying to implement the security yourself on the client!

As already mentioned in the previous answer; once you've got the password is should be salted and hashed and never stored in the database (or log files for that matter) in plain text.